# Buttons and forms using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am very new at this so any help is appreciated. 
I have 4 buttons on one page and a form for each button(forms are not visible). I need to know how to use jquery to make the form show up on the same page after I click the button. 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: provide your html to?

Comment: I have only been doing this for less than 30 days. I am not sure what html to post. Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: So I am new and you mark me negative one, then I ask for your help and you leave me with no help to what I asked you so I can make better posts? You do not seem to be a reasonable person.

Comment: Bro that's negative mark is not by me. This community have thousands of members

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to relate `button` → `form` with `data-*` attribute

```
<button data-toggle="#form1">Toggle #form1</button>
<button data-toggle="#form2">Toggle #form2</button>

<form id="form1">I'm form 1</form>
<form id="form2">I'm form 2</form>
```

jQuery will target the ID stored inside the `data-toggle` attribute

```
$("[data-toggle]").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this.dataset.toggle).stop().slideToggle(1000);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ev0egwpy/

Comment: Thanks for the help Roko